# Relationship between determinants and the augmented coefficient matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am trying to solve the following problem:

What is the relationship between determinants and the augmented coefficient matrix? Use the terms principal determinant and Cramer's rule to explain them.

Should we just mention the formula of Cramer's rule? Or what is the relationship?

Comment: What do you mean by "extended coefficient matrix"

Comment: I meant augmented coefficient matrix. I edited it also in my question above. Do you have an idea what we are supposed to say here? @JeanMarie

Comment: One can say that the determinants used in Cramers' rule are all the $n \times n$ determinants that can be computed from the $n \times (n+1)$ augmented matrix by cancelling a column in all possible ways. But "what else ?"...

Comment: I see! But we have to use also the term "prinicipal determinant". What can we say about that? @JeanMarie

Comment: The principal determinant is one of the determinants I have mentionned : the one obtained by the removal of the last column of the augmented matrix.